# need a flash like menu in jquery

Tags: jquery, flash, menu

can any on help me to design the menu like following sample site in jquery http://www.templatemonster.com/flash-templates/27517.html

```
    <script src="script/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>        
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            changesize();
            $("ul#selected li").click(function(){
                var selection=$(this).index();                                        
                var count = $("#selected").children().length;
                var mid=Math.floor(count/2)+1;
                var i;                   
                parseInt(mid);
                if(selection<mid)
                {
                  var  rotation=selection+mid;
                    for(i=1;i<=rotation;i++)
                        $('#selected li:first').appendTo('ul');
                        changesize();
                }                    
                else
                {

                    for(i=selection;i>=mid;i--)
                        {

                        $('#selected li:first').appendTo('ul');


                        }
                        changesize();
                }
        });

    });
    function changesize()
    {
        var height=80;
        var minheight=10;
        var count = $("#selected").children().length;
        var mid=Math.floor(count/2)+1;
        var i,divider,hv;
        for(i=1;i<=count;i++)
                    {
                        if(i<mid){divider=count-i;}
                        else if(i>mid){divider=(i-1);}
                        else
                            divider=1;
                        if(divider!=1)
                        hv=(height/minheight*count*4)/divider;
                        else
                            hv=height;                            
                        $('ul li:nth-child('+i+')').find('img').css('width', hv);

                    }
    }
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        ul li{float: left;list-style: none;margin:2px;margin-top: -5px;position: relative; }
        ul li img{position:relative;top: 0px;border: none; }
    </style>

    <ul id="selected">
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/img1.gif" alt=""/></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/img2.gif" alt=""/></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/img3.gif" alt=""/></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/img4.gif" alt=""/></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/img5.gif" alt=""/></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/img6.gif" alt=""/></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/img7.gif" alt=""/></a></li>
    </ul>
```

i have completed 90% of this work i need to add some animation in this please help me

Comment: This is a Q&A site, nobody is just going to do that for you. What have you got so far?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could try this tutorial.

[Create a Vertical Scrolling Menu with CSS and jQuery](http://valums.com/vertical-scrolling-menu/)

Answer (score 0):

1. It would involve having a list of elements (think ul) with each element floating. Your first goal would to be to create a horizontal list of elements or images.
2. The next step would be to give the li containers some negative margins so they overlap.
3. Then you would give each li a z-index (highest being the front element, then decreasing as you go along).
4. The JavaScript would be fairly simple, you would animate the width and heights of the a tag or image (depending on what you used).
5. I've included some code at the bottom; but the elements expand the entire list. Add some transparency and figure out a way to make the elements remain in their position and you've got it!

**Alternative 1**: You could compromise a bit (I know it's different but it might work). You might be satisfied with a [JQuery Fisheye](http://www.ajaxdaddy.com/demo-interface-fisheye.html)(Just one of many).

**Alternative 2:** You could spend $65 and get the complete Flash version ;)

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Stack Overflow Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">            
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".monsterMenu li a img").mouseover(function(){
                $(this).stop().animate({width:138,height:138},300,function(){
                    $(this).animate({width:128,height:128});
                });
            });
        });
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
        .monsterMenu{
            margin-left:64px;
            list-style:none;
        }
        .monsterMenu li{
            float:left;
            margin-left:-64px; /*64 is half of 128 (the image size)*/
        }
        .monsterMenu li a{
            position:relative;
        }
        .monsterMenu li a img{position:relative;}
        #mm1,#mm3{z-index:8;}
        #mm2{z-index:16;}
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <ul class="monsterMenu">
        <li ><a id="mm1" href=""><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4d/Crystal_Clear_action_lock_-_pink.png"/></a></li>
        <li><a id="mm2" href=""><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/09/Crystal_Clear_action_info.png"/></a></li>
        <li><a id="mm3" href=""><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fe/Crystal_Clear_app_browser.png"/></a></li>
    </ul>
</body>
```